# Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, запрос

Есть такой запрос:

```js
$sel = $conn -> query("SELECT * FROM goods WHERE name LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT $start, 12");
if ($sel -> num_rows > 0) {
  $out = array();
  while ($row = $sel - > fetch_assoc()) {
    $out[] = $row;
  }
  echo json_encode($out);
}
```

выдает ошибку

> **Notice**:  Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in **W:\domains\colorShop\core\classes\render.php** on line **42**

Запрос вроде как правильный.
В сессии любая строка, например 'аб'
В чем тут проблема?

Comment: пробельчик между минусом и больше уберите. `- >` => `->`

Comment: в реале его нет, это функция править сделала)

Comment: Ошибка говорил о том, что $sel не содержит объект. Функция query возвращает false в случае если не удалось выполнить запрос. Для того чтобы понять, что за ошибка, используйте - var_dump(mysqli_error($conn));

Answer (score 0):

```
$sel = $conn -> query("SELECT * FROM goods WHERE name LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT $start, 12");

if($sel) {
   // Lets Go'
} else {
   echo $sel->error;
}
```